# PHP URL verification and if not valid fix it

Tags: php

I am trying to verify URLs. This is the code I have:

```
function isValidURL($url) 
{
    return preg_match('|^http(s)?://[a-z0-9-]+(.[a-z0-9-]+)*(:[0-9]+)?(/.*)?$|i', $url);
}
```

This code is working but now I am trying to work out how to add `http://` or `https://` if the URL is correct but is just missing the beginning `http://`

Please point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix the HTTP(s) issue with Regex, you may set `http(s)?://` between parentheses and make it optional with `?`:

```
var_dump(isValidURL("stackoverflow.com/questions/15453684/php-url-verification-and-if-not-valid-fix-it"));

function isValidURL($url) {
 return preg_match('|^(http(s)?://)?[a-z0-9-]+(.[a-z0-9-]+)*(:[0-9]+)?(/.*)?$|i', $url);
}
```

**EDIT:**
Thanks to DCSoft, it seems that the above regex also validates something like `fijsfsdufd`, here's a quick fix, by adding a dot:

```
function isValidURL($url) {
 return preg_match('|^(http(s)?://)?[a-z0-9-]+\.(.[a-z0-9-]+)+(:[0-9]+)?(/.*)?$|i', $url);
}
```

[This may be interesting.](http://regexlib.com/REDetails.aspx?regexp_id=1854)

Comment: The problem with this is it lets the user type in what ever they want e.g - asdsaasdsad and it would still count it as being a valid URL

Comment: Thank you, it works perfectly but would you say for time optimization, it would be better to run it as a JavaScript on the form and stop the user submitting it or would it be better to do it in the php script?

Comment: @DCSoft Do it on both, never trust users input, they may just send it as HTTP/POST|GET request or disable JS

Comment: If I was going to do it as a javascript would the code be like - http://pastebin.com/aRPi7WHb

Comment: If you're using HTML5, try also to look at the `required` attribute by using something like `<input type="url" required="required">`

Answer (score 6):

Use the [filter functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.filter.php), there's a `FILTER_VALIDATE_URL` for this.

```
$is_valid_url = filter_var($url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL);
```

There's a bunch of options too, [see here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.validate.php).

To detect if there's a missing `http://` or not, just test your input without modifying it first, and try prepend it and test again if that fails.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `parse_url()` to verify your url
http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php

```
<?php

$url = "https://twitter.com?id=3232";
$url_info = parse_url($url);

echo "<pre>";
    print_r($url_info);
echo "</pre>";


?>
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [scheme] => https
    [host] => twitter.com
    [query] => id=3232
)
```

I believe you can even work with this function `parse_url` you will get lot of parameters easily and understandable format.

so your code will be

```
<?php

function isValidURL($url) {
    $varr = parse_url($url);
    if ($varr['scheme'] == 'https') {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
?>
```

Note : Url used above is not valid, its for testing purspose

Answer (score 1):

You can use [strpos](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) as such:

```
if (strpos($url,'http://') === false){
    $url = 'http://'.$url;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on [@seanwm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1476763/seanwm), here is a function that **checks and fixes the URL**.

**PHP function**

```
function fixUrl($url, $forceSSL = false) {

    if (strpos($url,'http://') === false 
    && strpos($url,'https://') === false) {

        if($forceSSL) {
            return 'https://'.$url;
        }

        return 'http://'.$url;
    }

    return $url;
}
```

**Use**

For *http://* :

```
$url = fixUrl($url);
```

force to prepend *https://* :

```
$url = fixUrl($url, true);
```